# Passando parâmetros para o método as_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando passar parâmetros para o método as_json(sobrescrevendo o método) no meu model. Pois só com a data que vem do usuário que posso retornar o meu resultado. De acordo com essa data passada eu adiciono um campo ao json de retorno. Podemos chamar de "novo_valor" o valor a ser inserido ao json final;

Minha dúvida é como atualizar o json e se essa maneira de passar os parâmetros no render :json... está correta.

Ambiente de desenvolvimento:

- Rails 4
- Ruby 2.0.0

Dentro do meu controller da minha api:

```
 render :json => @schedules.as_json({:date => params[:date]})
```

No meu model

```
def as_json(options={})
  if options.has_key?(:date)
    # obtém novo valor
    # adiciona novo_valor ao json de retorno
  end
  # Deve manter o comportamento do as_json, que penso ser só a chamada super(options). Pois ele deve continuar e chamar o método to_json, caso contrário recebo um erro.
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui encontrar a solução:

No meu controller:

```
render :json => @schedules.as_json({:date => date})
```

No meu model:

```
def as_json(options = nil)
  hash = super(options)

  if options.has_key?(:date)
    date = options[:date]
    hash.merge!({ :number_of_available_vacancies => number_of_available_vacancies(date)})
  end

  hash
end
```